# Merge recovery partition with the main one in ASUS T100T?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, asus-laptop

I have `Asus T100T` laptop. It has a `7 GB` *Recovery Partition*. I'm trying to merge it with the `29 GB` partition. But the *Recovery Partition* seems protected somehow.

### Steps I've tried but didn't work out:

**Workaround 1**

> **Steps:**
>
> **1.** `X:\Sources>diskpart`
>    **2.** `list disk`
>    **3.** `select disk 1`
>    **4.** `list partition`
>    **5.** `select partition 1`
>    **6.** Either `clean` or `delete partition override`
>
> **Result:**
>
> `Diskpart has encountered an error: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error. See the System Event Log for more information.`

**Workaround 2**

> **Steps:**
>
> **1.** `X:\Sources>diskpart`
>    **2.** `list disk`
>    **3.** `select disk 1`
>    **4.** `list volume`
>    **5.** `select volume 0`
>    **6.** `delete volume override`
>
> **Result:**
>
> A window popups saying`The instruction at 0x000962D6 referenced memory at 0x00000000. The memory could not be read. Click on Ok to terminate the program.`

**Workaround 3**

> **Steps:**
>
> **1.** `X:\Sources>diskpart`
>    **2.** `list disk`
>    **3.** `select disk 1`
>    **4.** `list volume`
>    **5.** `select volume 0`
>    **6.** `attributes volume clear readonly`
>
> **Result:**
>
> `Virtual Disk Service error: The object is not found.`

Comment: I assume you've been through the BIOS/EFI and turned off all secure boot/boot sector protection/trusted execution related featuers?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq I think I've not edited anything like that. How could I approve this?